# Notify a page when another page is requested

Tags: notify

I have three pages:
The first inserts some info into the DB.
The second inserts some new info into the DB, when it is requested
The third shows this information

How to notify the third page when the second updates the info?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Redirect to it from page 2 and append GET parameters such as `http://www.your.url/page3?changed=true`

Have a check on page 3 for parameters and behave accordingly.

Comment: What is «notify a page» then? The page isn't just sitting there, it's generated upon a request, such as the one that happens right after a redirect. If you don't want to do that, then just write something to a database, and read it every time page 3 is loaded to see if changes have occured or not.